# Counting a variant of de Bruijn sequence where not every substring needs to appear

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Are there any existing textbooks/articles/papers discussing a variant of de Bruijn sequence where not all substrings (I am specifically looking for when a fixed total number of substrings occur only once) need to occur? I want to count those. I believe the following is an equivalent and specific way to phrase the problem.

I want to count the number of unique possible length-$m$ substrings of some de Bruijn sequence on alphabet $\{ A, C, T, G\}$ with order $n$. (It should be an equivalent formulation because if not all substrings occur once, then it must be a substring of some de Bruijn sequence, the only problem that stops me from counting now is that two different de Bruijn sequences might have same substrings of length $m$, which I don't know how to deal with.)

Comment: I don't think the second paragraph is equivalent to the first.  There might be a length-$m$ string $S$ s.t. no length-$n$ substring has repeated, _but_ it is impossible to complete it into a de Brujin sequence of length $|\Sigma|^n$.  E.g., if you use the normal interpretation of de Brujin sequence as cyclic, then for $\Sigma = \{0,1\}, n=2$ the length-$3$ string $L=010$ has no repeated length-$2$ substrings (even if you interpret it cyclically) but you cannot add another $0$ or $1$ without making it contain repeated length-$2$ substring (if you interpret it cyclically)